# What is the Lodash function opposite of _.pull/_.pullAll?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I use `_.pullAll(source, removed_values)` to remove a set of values from an array (modifying it).

But inside the [Lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/) I cannot find which is the opposite function inside *Lodash*: one that **modifies a `source` array, pushing inside it all the values from an `added_values` array**.

Cause of the specific namings in the library I often have this problem of finding how is the opposite of one function named.

Comment: how about https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#union or https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#concat ?

Comment: `_.union([arrays])` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! 

Comment: Actually, coming back to this question, I found out that neither `union` or `concat` **modify** the source array. Am I missing something? Is there a *real* opposite of `pullAll`?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do a logical not on pullAllWith, it will still work similarly to a filter.

So for instance:

```
_.pullAllWith(
   [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}], 
   [1, 2], //removing this
   (obj, objId) => obj.id === objId
)
```

result: `[{id: 3}]` (Removing objects with id 1, 2)

let's say you wanted to *keep* `{id: 3}`, just logically not the equality operator

```
_.pullAllWith(
   [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}], 
   [3], //keeping this
   (obj, objId) => obj.id !== objId
)
```

result: `[{id: 3}]`